# chat room constantly re-loading

Tags: support, chat, auto-login

> Loading The Whiteboard
>
> Just a second...

This notice is popping up every a few seconds making chat unusable at least for that [channel](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard). I got the same results on Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera.

Is anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: This may happens because of your slow internet speed.

Comment: it's anything but slow (the reloads happen really fast), unreliable maybe

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this is related to the auto-login mechanism, problem ceased after I logged in through: https://stackexchange.com/users/chat-login

Comment: The link you provided leads to a possibly offensive image. Sorry about that.